# Can we run Selenium Webdriver Tests without interactive mode

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, interactive

Im running my selenium test on different browsers using selenium webdiver, but they all need interactive mode for runnung the tests, can we run these tests without interactive mode?

Comment: What do you mean with `interactive` mode?

Comment: For chrome and firefox, you can minimize the browser window during test running, but IE should not support that.

Comment: I mean when the tests are running we need to make sure that brower on which the test is running should active, not in minimize mode and not running in background, i want to get rid of this.

Comment: @yong i have run the tests using an agent on chrome but it as still the same issue

Comment: Did your script do some things like mouse over on page? Generally, for click, sendkeys not require browser window is active ( obtain the focus).  But mouse over only work on the active browser window.

Comment: My script do everything like, button click, sendkeys, mouse over etc. Is there still any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for this:

**1.**
You could use headless testing method, try using HtmlUnitDriver, PhantomJSDriver,

**2.**
use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) with pre-set image, here is the [example](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-selenium-tests-in-docker)

Bellow are code examples for headless tests,(although in java, I see You're looking in c#), but it might help

**HTMLdriver**

```
@Test
public void runHtmlHeadless() {
    String URl = "https://www.google.com";
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver.get(URl);
    System.err.println("TITLE: " + driver.getTitle());
}
```

**Chrome**

```
  @Test
  public void createChromeDriverHeadless() throws IOException
  {

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/user/Downloads/chromedriver");

      ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
      chromeOptions.setBinary("//Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
      chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
      driver.navigate().to("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login");

      WebDriverWait waitForUsername = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
      waitForUsername.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));

      driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("tomsmith");
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.radius")).click();

      WebDriverWait waitForError = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
      waitForError.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("flash")));

      Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("flash")).getText().contains("Your password is invalid!"));
      driver.quit();
  }
```

Hope this helps,